# Is there a way to use one httpget request to handle multiple query string parameters in c#?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am new to c# and using controllers for that matter. The below code works by querying for a parameter using api/Accounts?mgmId=00u100gp4rDgSjGup1t7

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Accounts>>> GetAccountDataAsync(string? mgmId)
        {
            try
            {
                string query = $"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.MGMId=@mgmId";
                QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(query).WithParameter("@mgmId", mgmId);
                var account = await _accountService.GetAccountDataAsync(queryDefinition);
                return Ok(account);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
                return StatusCode(404, "Not Found");
            }
        }
```

What I would like to do is pass something like the following so I could query by any key, not only mgmId, in a CosmosDb database.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Accounts>>> GetAccountDataAsync(Accounts acc)
        {
            try
            {
                string query = $"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.MGMId=@mgmId";
                QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(query).WithParameter("@mgmId", acc.MGMId);
                var account = await _accountService.GetAccountDataAsync(queryDefinition);
                return Ok(account);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
                return StatusCode(404, "Not Found");
            }
        }
```

I am putting my Accounts.cs below

```
    public class Accounts
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public string? Id { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyName("MGMId")]
        public string MGMId { get; set; } = null!;
        [JsonPropertyName("MlifeId")]
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
        public long MlifeId { get; set; } = 0!;
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
        public long? OperaId {get; set;}
        [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
        public object? Profile {get; set;}
        
    }
```

And this is my AccountsService

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Accounts>> GetAccountDataAsync(QueryDefinition queryString)
        {
            var query = this._container.GetItemQueryIterator<Accounts>(queryString);
            List<Accounts> results = new List<Accounts>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var response = await query.ReadNextAsync();

                results.AddRange(response.ToList());
            }
            return results;
        }
```

This is the Error I get when trying to pass the Accounts as a parameter by model binding:
"errors": {
"$": [
"The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
],
"acc": [
"The acc field is required."
]

Comment: Thanks Rahul. I used the [FromQuery] and that worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your scenario, you need to add `FromQuery` attribute to get your data for the GET operation:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Accounts>>> GetAccountDataAsync([FromQuery]Accounts acc)
```

You can read more on parameter binding on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0).